# What is wrong with year's and year here?

Tags: pronouns, possessives

I wrote this sentence:

> In India, many aspirants take a year break to crack competitive exams so that they can study in a premier institute.

My teacher corrected it to:

> In India, many aspirants take a **year's** break to crack competitive exams so that they can study in a premier institute.

Why do we need year's over there? I understand possessive noun but I am a bit confused here. Why year's is required here? When I am writing *a year break*, it means 1 year break. What does *a year's break* mean here? Also, why is it required here?

Comment: You could also write "a [yearlong](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/yearlong) break".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [apostrophe-s](http://www.grammar.cl/rules/genitive-case.htm) is used to to indicate the genitive, which can be used to indicated possession, quantity or relationship. **Of** does a similar job, but people often show strong preferences for one form or the other in a particular situation.

In this case, **a year** is quantity: we are saying that they are taking **a year of break**. The preferred genitive in this case is **a year's break**.

Note that, when the noun we attach the apostrophe-s to is plural, the order of the apostrophe and the s is reversed:

> John has ten years' experience

some people don't like this form, an prefer to write it as

> John has ten years of experience.